# Generating Forms with Ember.js and EmberFire

Tags: javascript, ember.js, firebase, emberfire

I have a table thats generated by an `{{#each}}` loop and it displays user's first and last names. I want to add a delete button to delete the record on that row. I am also using EmberFire to connect with Firebase.

**What is the best way to associate the data in that row with that delete button?**

Heres the wee bit of relevant code I have:

`index.html`

```
{{#each}}
  <tr>
    <td>
      {{this.first}}
    </td>
    <td>{{this.last}}</td>
    <td>
      <button>X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

`router.js`

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return EmberFire.Array.create({
      ref: new Firebase(FirebaseRef + 'testObj')
    });
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('index');
    this.render('users', { 
      outlet: 'users',
      into  : 'index'
    });
  }
});
```

`controller.js`

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    register: function() {
      this.pushObject({
        'first' : this.get('firstName'),
        'last'  : this.get('lastName')
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a delete action to your IndexController:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    register: function() {
      this.pushObject({
        'first' : this.get('firstName'),
        'last'  : this.get('lastName')
      });
    },
    delete: function(person) {
        this.content.removeObject(person);
    }
  }
})
```

Then add the following to your index.html:

```
{{#each}}
  <tr>
    <td>
      {{this.first}}
    </td>
    <td>{{this.last}}</td>
    <td>
      <button {{action "delete" this}}>X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Yup, that did it! I had assumed that I would need to do some sort of manual data binding to each row and it's button. I guess I'll chock this one up to Ember's magic :) Thanks!